# php the most effective search array of objects by object`s field

Tags: php

I got an array of objects which may consist of very many elements, more than thousands of hundreds etc. The object may look like the following:

```
object(Node)#21489 (15) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(7) "balance"
  ["type"]=>
  string(1) "4"//...and so other fields
}
```

I need to search the array of objects to find and object with certain id. Currently I can do it with the help of `foreach` loop, like this:

```
 foreach($nodes_array as $node) {
        if ($node->id == 'my certain id') {
            return $node;
        }
    }
```

but the problem is that it takes too loooong to traverse the whole array to find needed object. Is there a more effective way (or refactoring approach) to make such search faster (may be with iterators or smth else)?
Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you could use this [array search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: You won't get any better than `O(n)` anyway, unless you completely restructure your source data into a map of `id -> node` - but if you do that by looping through your source array, then it's `O(n)` again (although it only needs doing once, so it's better if you need to access several IDs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this once

```
$nodes_array2 = [];
foreach($nodes_array as $node) {
     $nodes_array2[$node->id] = $node;
unset($nodes_array);
```

Then

```
return $nodes_array2['my certain id'];
```